# Separate Bibliography from Last Heading

Tags: org-mode, org-ref

I'm trying to use org-ref and I'm doing pretty well. There is one thing bothering me, though. The bibliography gets attached to the last heading (in the org file), where-as I would like it to be separate.

```
#+TITLE: Title

#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{natbib}

* Section 1
* Section 2
** Subsection 2.1
** Subsection 2.2

# Maybe add a * Bibliography heading here? But how to hide it?

bibliographystyle:unsrt  # These get attached to subsection 2.2
bibliography:project.bib
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Are you talking about the Org mode buffer or are you talking about the PDF file that will be produced when you export? Please edit your question to clarify that and also what you mean by "attached" and "separate".

Answer (score 1):

That bothered me too. My solution was to add `#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand{\bibsection}{}` and keep those `bibliography:` and `bibliographystyle:` links under a References (or whatever you like) heading. So, you are not hiding the heading in .org, but the one that is generated by the link, in order to avoid a duplicate. So, in your case you can do:

```
#+TITLE: Title
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{natbib}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand{\bibsection}{}

* Section 1
* Section 2
** Subsection 2.1
** Subsection 2.2
* Bibliography
bibliographystyle:unsrt
bibliography:project.bib
```